# Execute an "INSERT INTO" in the HeaderRow using RowCommand

Tags: asp.net, gridview, insert-into

I am trying to execute an "INSERT INTO" in the HeaderRow.

The button in the HeaderRow does not trigger the RowCommand.

The gridview contains 5 columns: idt, datetime, col1, col2 and col3.

```
Protected Sub gvtest_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvtest.RowCommand
    Dim txt1, txt2, txt3 as String
    If e.CommandName = "insertinto" Then
        Try
            txt1 = DirectCast(gvtest.HeaderRow.FindControl("tbins1"), TextBox).Text
            txt2 = DirectCast(gvtest.HeaderRow.FindControl("tbins2"), TextBox).Text
            txt3 = DirectCast(gvtest.HeaderRow.FindControl("tbins3"), TextBox).Text
            sqltest.InsertParameters("@datetime").DefaultValue = DateTime.Now()
            sqltest.InsertParameters("@col1").DefaultValue = txt1
            sqltest.InsertParameters("@col2").DefaultValue = txt2
            sqltest.InsertParameters("@col3").DefaultValue = txt3                
            sqltest.Insert()
        Catch ex As Exception
            TextBox1.Text = "Insert: " & ex.Message
        End Try
        gvtest.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

default.aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvtest"
    runat="server"
    DataSourceID="sqltest"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="idt"
    OnRowCommand="gvtest_RowCommand">
<Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="idt" HeaderText="idt" Readonly="true" SortExpression="idt" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="datetime" HeaderText="datetime" SortExpression="datetime" />
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col1">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbins1" text="col1" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col2">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbins2" text="col2" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="col3">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbins3" text="col3" runat="server" MaxLength="40" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnins" CommandName="insertinto" runat="server" Text="Insert Into" OnClick="btnins_Click" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource
    id="sqltest"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connone %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [test];
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [test] datetime,col1,col2,col3 VALUES @datetime,@col1,@col2,@col3;">        
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Note for brevity  textboxes were omitted containing the gridview data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a known command name, like Insert.  It will not know your custom command name.

Read this:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

change:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnins" CommandName="insertinto" runat="server" Text="Insert Into" OnClick="btnins_Click" />
```

to:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnins" CommandName="Insert" runat="server" Text="Insert Into" OnClick="btnins_Click" />
```

Comment: that's not exactly right.  All "known" commands also pass thru the RowCommand event, it's just that they are "well known" and have standard events associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

GridView row command events come from the Command controls on the data rows.

You placed a button in the GridView header, you need to process the `btnins.Command` event